# Who viewed or opened an Exchange Appointment (EWS)

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, appointment

Is it possible the know which user viewed/opened a specific Outlook Appointment with the help of the EWS (Exchange Web Service) library ?

Ideal would be something like a history with the username of the user as well as the date and time at which that occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange does not store such history.

It's possible only if you create a custom plugin for Outlook (Desktop Client) and make sure that everyone's using it (will not work from a mobile client).